# is this proof correct (inverse of strictly increasing strictly increasing)?

Tags: real-analysis

suppose $f: A \to B$ bijective and strictly increasing. show $f^{-1}: B \to A$ strictly increasing

Here's my proof:

let $a, a' \in A$. without loss of generality, suppose $a < a'$

this implies $f(a) < f(a')$

suppose without loss of generality that $b, b' \in B$ s.t. $f(a) = b$ and $f(a') = b'$

then $b < b'$. we have that $f^{-1}(b) = a$ and $f^{-1}(b) = a'$

this implies $f^{-1}(b) < f^{-1}(b')$.

since $b, b'$ were arbitrary, this concludes the proof.

Is this reasoning correct? Not sure if I am missing anything.

Comment: Why are $b,b'$ arbitrary? You chose arbitrary $a,a'$, and $b,b'$ are defined from them. Not really convincing. If you want to show $f^{-1}$ is increasing then you should start from two elements $b,b'\in B$ (and not from elements of $A$ like you did) such that $b<b'$, and prove that $f^{-1}(b)<f^{-1}(b')$.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I was able to do so by starting with $b < b'$ and then supposing $ f^{-1}(b) \ge f^{-1}(b')$ and got a contradiction. Is there a direct way that you were thinking of?

Comment: Yeah, that's the proof. Don't think there is a more direct way here.

Comment: There’s a direct way by $b=f(f^{-1}(b))$, isn’t there?